# Initialization list std::pair

Tags: c++, stl

Is there a way of initializing a `std::vector` of `std::pair<int,int>` in the initialization list in a constructor? I have a `std::vector<std::pair<int,int> >` and I want to initialize a certain number of pairs to `(0, 0)`. For example, I may want to initialize 3 pairs of `(0, 0)` for a member in a class. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by using the `std::vector` constructor which takes in a size and a default value to use:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass();
    /* ... */

private:
    std::vector<pair<int, int> > elems;
};

MyClass::MyClass() : elems(3, std::make_pair(0, 0)) {
    /* ... */
}
```